# iOS - Using TPKeyboardAvoiding on two scroll views, they affect each other

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

It is so lucky to find the michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding to solve the Keyboard blocking text field problem. The TPKeyboardAvoiding is very nice. User just needs defining custom class as TPKeyboardAvoiding to make it happen.

My Question and Problem is:

In my condition, I have two views include scroll view. In each scroll view, there are sevral text fields. One view segue to other view. After segued view's last text field been edited, the previous view can't scroll to the last text filed.

All in all, after user editing one scroll view, the other view's content insets -> bottom value changed! Anyone has similar experience with me?

Correct one

[image: Correct one]

Wrong one

[image: Wrong one]

My unsuccessful try: I have tried copy another paire of TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.h & .m file into project, and renamed them.It doesn't work.
[image]

[image]

BTW, even the segued view can't raise last textfield up entirely. [image]

Answer (score 1):

I have not used TPKeyboardAvoid with two Scroll views but sometime using alternate framework might solve your problem  :

You can give try to following frameworks -

https://github.com/muanis/sampleapps_scrollview

https://github.com/kirpichenko/EKKeyboardAvoiding

https://github.com/freerunnering/SwipeSelection

https://github.com/rnystrom/RNAvatarLogin

https://github.com/lupidan/UIKeyboardCoView